# How to read an nxn matrix using pointers?

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C++ and i am trying to learn pointers. 
As a working exercise i try to read a nxn matrix using pointers to pointers.
This is what i have tried so far, but the scanf is failing.
What am i doing wrong?
Later edit:

```
int **matrix;
int i=0;
int j=0;
int li=0;
int dim;

printf("What is the dimmension:");
scanf("%d",&dim);
matrix=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * dim);
for(li=0;li<dim;li++)
{
    matrix[li] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * dim);
}
printf("Type the elements:\n");
for(i=0;i<dim;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<dim;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to access it like a regular 2d array `matrix[i][j]` then for `scanf` use the location of that

```
scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
```

Edit also you need to allocate the pointers themselves:

```
matrix=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * dim);
for(i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * dim);
}
```

Also if this is straight `C` you shouldn't cast the return type from malloc because `C` upgrades it automatically and the cast can hide a bug.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I saw that and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++ this better do like this

```
matrix = new int*[dim];
for(int = 0; i < dim; ++i)
    matrix[i] = new int[dim];

// to read matrix
scanf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
```

Comment: This is correct.  Although it's arguably more idiomatic (in modern C++) to use `std::array` (or `boost::multi_array`).

Answer (score 1):

You have two (and a half) main options. You can allocate each row individually,

```
matrix = malloc(dim * sizeof(int*));  // gives you dim int*
for(i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
{
    matrix[i] = malloc(dim * sizeof(int)); // row i gets dim int
}
```

or you can allocate a contiguous chunk

```
int *array = malloc(dim*dim*sizeof(int));
```

and access that with

```
array[i*dim + j];
```

The half option is to use the packed memory layout but have a wrapper to access it with `matrix[i][j]`:

```
int **matrix = malloc(dim*sizeof(int*));
for(i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
{
    matrix[i] = array + i*dim;
}
```

(Of course, in C++ you would normally not `malloc` but use `new` and/or other types provided by the standard library.)

Comment: +1. Deleted my answer after noticing your (mine was only first part of your) :)

Answer (score 0):

You've allocated the top-level array of pointers-to-pointers, but didn't set the next level of pointer to any allocated memory.  Make a loop to malloc a chunk for each pointer matrix[i], or set each pointer to existing allocated memory, then it can be used by scanf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do the array of pointers, where the pointers each point to a row, you are actually required to make the pointers for each row yourself.  Here is the code:

//forM*N (or N*N)

```
int **a;
a=malloc(M*sizeof(int *));
for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    a[i] = &aa[i][0];
```

With that code, you assign a a pointer to a large malloc, and then assign a chunk of the malloc to the first element of each row!  this allows you to de-reference the array using conventional 2d array a[0][0], a[1][1], ec.
Here is my best reference on explaining this:
http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html